# Github: when uploading a folder containing 30 subfolders, can I create just one gitignore?

Tags: git, github, project

I'm new to Github and just want to understand how to most efficiently upload my project, since I have so many to upload at one time. I have thirty project, and I know that I can:

> "upload the entire folder containing all your projects and have a web
>   page link to each of the subfolders seperately whilst keeping them all
>   contained in one repository."

However, does this means that I can create ONE gitignore for all off the projects, or will I still have to create a gitignore for each individual subfolder?? Is there a way I could create just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a global gitignore on your machine as explained in [the docs](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/):

> ### Create a global .gitignore
>
> You can also create a global .gitignore file, which is a list of rules
>   for ignoring files in every Git repository on your computer. For
>   example, you might create the file at ~/.gitignore_global and add some
>   rules to it.
>
> Open Terminal. Run the following command in your terminal:
>
> ```
> git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
> ```

*Note* that this is **client** machine specific though so each person who checks out your repo would need this setting up. The server never "ignores" files as each repo is isolated.